# Is it possible to use Junit for Deltaspike Data Module Repository testing?

Tags: jpa, junit, dbunit, deltaspike

I really like using the Deltaspikes Datamodule with its Repositories.
To improve in productivity and lower the Errors i am also writing Unittests via JUnit.
Before i used DBUnit with Plain JPA/Hibernate inside the testcases, but i would like
to test my deltaspike JPA repositories via JUnit - or maybe enhanced with DBUnit.
Are there any best practises or ways how to do this?
I found some integration project that combines dbunit with Deltaspike, but i was not able to getit running with Hibernate JPA Provider.

https://github.com/lbitonti/deltaspike-dbunit

Thanking you very much in advance for any help

Best regards, Shane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by using Database Rider.
I really can recommend this project for all people who want to have a foll integrated JUnit 5 Test combined with Apache Deltaspikes Repository structure

https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider